# Hue do not have column description

Tags: hive, hue

Hive has column description,but hue do not show column description,
[this is hue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rLl7.png)

[this is hive metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06ZrC.png)

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed recently, on which Hue version are you? It might be good in 4.8, or will be in the future 4.9 or already in master branch.